# Abstract model error

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have problem about the abstract model in chapter "Adding Easy Admin Emails, Helpers, Sitemaps, and More" (the hello web app intermediate book)
here is my models.py code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Timestamp(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Thing(Timestamp):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)


class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/things/%s/" % self.slug


class Social(models.Model):
    SOCIAL_TYPES = (
        ('twitter','Twitter'),
        ('facebook','Facebook'),
        ('pinterest','Pinterest'),
        ('instagram','Instagram'),
    )
    network = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=SOCIAL_TYPES)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    thing = models.ForeignKey(Thing,related_name="social_accounts")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Social media links"
```

---

when I run

```
$python manage.py makemigrations
$python manage.py migrate
```

the error message shows:

```
/helloApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py:309: RuntimeWarning: Model 'collection.thing' was already registered. Reloading models is not advised as it can lead to inconsistencies, most notably with related models.
  new_class._meta.apps.register_model(new_class._meta.app_label, new_class)

No changes detected
```

---

that does not show like in the book :

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'added' to thing without a defaul,,,,,,,
```

any answer would very greatful thank you!

Comment: You've got two models called Thing there. I am certain that is not what the book shows.

Comment: right ,,I thought that is follow the previous book code so I just add the class Timestamp(models.Model): ,,,,,and class Thing(Timestamp): ,,,. on it

Comment: so should I separate two models.py ???

Comment: No. You should not have two models called Thing at all.

Comment: I do not get it??the book said create the abstract model can tie with main model ???

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. You don't need two models called Thing. You need *one* model, containing all those fields, which inherits from Timestamp.

Comment: thank you,,,when I #out the class Thing(Timestamp):,,,,. and change the class Thing(models.Model): ,,,.to class Thing(Timestamp) , it can run like this "You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'added' to thing without a defaul,,,,,,,"